# Random sampling based on vector of probability weights

Tags: r, probability, sampling

I have the vector `d<-1:100`

I want to sample k=3 times from this vector **without replacement**. I would like to make elements that are at a distance  `length(d)/k` from the first sampled element to have a higher probability of getting sampled. I am not yet sure how much higher. I know that `sample` has a `prob=` argument, however i can't seem to find a way so that the `prob=` vectors gets to be recalculated from the location of the initial sample.

Any ideas?

**Example:** 
`d<-1:100` . Lets say the first trial samples `d[30]=30`. Then the elements of `ddd` that are near 0, 60 and 90 should have a higher probability of sampling. So after the initial sample the the distribution of the sampling probabilities of the rest of the elements of `ddd` is as in the image: [image]

Comment: Since you are sampling without replacement, how do you see the probabilities changing if the samples at the desired offsets are unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

```
samp <- sample(1:100,1)
prob <- rep(1,100)
prob[samp]=0
```

MORE EDIT: I'm an idiot today. Now this will make the probability shape you asked for.

```
peke<-c(2,5,7,10,7,5,2)  #your 'triangle' probability
for (jj = c(0,2,3){
prob[(1:7)*(1+samp*(jj)] <- peke
}
newsamp <-sample(1:100,1,prob)
```

You may want to add a slight offset if that doesn't place the probability peaks where you wanted them.